# Traefik v2 - Add Unique Trace ID to the header

Tags: docker, http, traefik

I wish to add a unique UUID\X-Request-ID\Trace-ID to a header using a middleware. Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: traefik
    environment:
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB=web
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB_ADDRESS=:80
      - TRAEFIK_API_INSECURE=true # Enable Dashboard
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER=true # Enable Docker Provider
      - TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=INFO # Set Log level to INFO
      - TRAEFIK_ACCESSLOG=true # Enable Access Logs
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  headers:
    image: akalipetis/headers:latest # This image prints all the HTTP Headers
    container_name: headers
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.headers.middlewares=testHeader"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.testHeader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Trace-Id=12345"
      - "traefik.http.services.headers.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.headers.rule=Host(`headers.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.headers.entrypoints=web"
```

I want to assign the value of the UUID\X-Request-ID\Trace-ID to `X-Trace-ID`. Adding a Trace-ID would be the best option. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504845/how-to-add-a-unique-request-id-header-to-traefik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is you can set an HTTP header (X-Request-ID in this case) for this:

```
version: "3.3"


services:

  traefik:

    image: traefik:v2.4

    container_name: traefik

    environment:

        ....
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER=true # Enable Docker Provider

      - TRAEFIK_TRACING=true # Enable Tracing

      - TRAEFIK_TRACING_JAEGER_SAMPLINGPARAM=0 # Set the Jaeger sampling parameter

      - TRAEFIK_TRACING_JAEGER_TRACECONTEXTHEADERNAME=X-Request-ID # Set the header to use for the X-Request-ID
        ....

    volumes:

      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```